# PHP form error logic

Tags: php

Normally when  we submit form in php and show errors then the errors are posted in other page. 
Now my question is.

1. If we want to show the errors on same page mean on the form page, then how to do it?
2. I used session  for that and found it better then other process but when I want to show all session variable at once then it will not show, why?

My code is:

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) {
            $user =test_input($_POST['user']);
            $pass = test_input($_POST['pass']);
            $securepassword=hash('sha512', $pass);

         if(empty($user)&&empty($pass))
{
echo 'fill every field';
}
else if(empty($user)||empty($pass))
{
echo  'fill both the field';
}
else
{
             $sSQL = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Username ='".$user."' AND Password = '".$securepassword."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sSQL) or die(mysql_error());
            $row=mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($row==1)
            {
                // Set username session variable
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                // Jump to secured page
                header('location:index.php');
            }

            else
            {
                header('location:signin.php');
            }
            }
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution: put your code on same page as the form

Comment: Mark is right, the errors do display on the page. Think about it, there are no errors in the submitted data on the form page because no data has been submitted. What you *might* be after is JavaScript validation of form input (it'll check values either as you type or before submitting) combined with posting to self would produce your desired results

Answer (score 0):

You better use JavaScript for validating the form. Lets say this is your HTML code.

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="abc.php">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="password" name="pass">
</form>
```

Now, let’s add validate this form before you `POST` to `abc.php`:

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="abc.php" onsubmit="return validater()">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="password" name="pass">
</form>
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
function validater() {
    var a= document.forms["loginForm"]["user"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="") {
        alert("Fill out the username");
        return false;
    }
    var b= document.forms["loginForm"]["pass"].value;
    if (b==null || b=="") {
        alert("Enter your password");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite answering the question. Although a good lesson on js validation, perhaps think about including posting to self (php) explanation and the session data answer.

Comment: Yes, or may be he/she could use ajax to validate it with php. Although, there are variety of options, I feel this is the best. Do you think, it is necessary to refresh the page just to check if the string entered is empty? ;)

@Jake Thanks for the edit jake. I'm new here. :)

Comment: No but if you read the original question, you might see where I'm coming from. Although this may be what the asker actually wants, it's not strictly what they asked for. They asked about php errors being displayed, not form validation.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is simple you can put the php code and html code on the same page. In the following order.

1. Put your php validation code.
2. Put your error code to show errors above the form.
3. Put your html code to show the form fields on the page.

There is no need of session to show errors to the user.